# Написать код на Java, который бы выводил количество максимальных элементов непустого массива, используя при этом только один цикл

Tags: java, массивы

Доброго времени суток!
Вот что получилось у меня. Выводит нужный результат, но через 2 цикла.

Как сделать с одним?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] dArray = {20, 13, 20, 14, 20, 14};

        int max = 0;
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++) {
            if (max < dArray[i])
                max = dArray[i];

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++) {
            if (dArray[i] == max) k++;
        }
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Гениально! Никогда бы не догадался как сделать это при помощи двух или более циклов.

Answer (score 3):

Просто надо обнулять `k` если появляется новый максимум. А если максимум совпадает со значением массива - то увеличивать это `k`

Пример так:

```
int[] dArray = {21, 20, 13, 20, 14, 20, 14, 21};

int max = 0;
int countMax = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++) {
    if (max < dArray[i]) {
        max = dArray[i];
        countMax = 0;
    }

    if (max == dArray[i])
        countMax++;
}

System.out.println(countMax);
```

http://ideone.com/dHCpw7

Comment: Благодарю, всё оказалось так просто.

Answer (score 3):

Например, вот так:

`public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] dArray = {20, 13, 20, 14, 20, 14};
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // Отрицательные разве невозможны? 
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++) {
      if (dArray[i] > maxValue) { 
        maxValue = dArray[i];
        maxCount = 1;
      } else if (dArray[i] == maxValue) maxCount++; 
    }
    System.out.printf("Найдено %d вхождений значения %d\n", 
                        maxCount, maxValue);
  }
}`